# How I get Guice and TestNg playing along, a-la-AtUnit style

Tags: unit-testing, guice, testng, atunit

I'm using TestNG for unit & integration tests, and Guice for DI. I would like to treat my test classes like other classes - instead of directly working with the injector, I would rather define fields marked with @Inject, and get these injected before each test.

Is there a framework that does this? I believe that [AtUnit](http://code.google.com/p/atunit/) does something similar, but I'm not sure how it integrates with TestNG, nor how mature it is.

Comment: I don't know about testNg but if you use jBehave it's really easy having Steps classes managed by Guice.

Answer (score 4):

Cedric has now added a `@Guice` annotation directly into TestNG to facilitate this use case.

- Docs: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#guice-dependency-injection (up to date)
- Background post: http://beust.com/weblog/2010/12/10/testng-and-guice-a-marriage-made-in-heaven/ (*slightly* changed since post!)

Answer (score 3):

TestNG uses Guice internally but it also makes it very easy to have your test classes injected before TestNG sees them (using Guice or whatever other framework you prefer).

All you need to do is implement [IObjectFactory](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IObjectFactory.html) and then declare your class name when you launch TestNG with -objectfacfory.

Then TestNG will delegate all object creations to your factory, which allows you to create your instances and inject them before returning them to TestNG.

Comment: Cedric has now built this into TestNG directly. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of how to use this and have it interact with TestNG.xml groups look at my blog entry http://biggerwrench.blogspot.com/2014/02/testng-using-guice-for-dependency.html